# Migration from JS to TS, Jest doesn't see "globals"

Tags: javascript, typescript, migration, ts-jest

I recently migrated my [code base](https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger) from JS to TS and everything is looking good so far.

The issue I am facing is that when I try to change the test file extensions to `.ts` or `.tsx` as needed, Jest no longer sees all my global variables and setup files.

My [package.json](https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger/blob/master/package.json), [jest.config.js](https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger/blob/master/config/jest.config.js), and [tsconfig.development.json](https://github.com/lbragile/TabMerger/blob/master/config/tsconfig.development.json).

Is the only solution to use a library like `ts-jest` (I would like to avoid this if possible)?

If so, I tried previously and wasn't able to get it working (same issue as above). Could someone please kindly provide some hints in the right direction?

Comment: Where are you defining your globals? How are you using them? You can creation a `XXX.d.ts` file to keep track of your external global variables (like the ones you set in .env or webpack, etc.).

Comment: You can see all my code in the links I shared. My globals are defined in “tests/__mocks__/variableMocks.js” also I do have a folder named “src/typings/“ where I keep “.d.ts” files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to add `ts-jest` explicitly. the latest `jest` uses `ts-jest` as default to transform your `.ts(x)` files. Here are the steps to make your tests work with only `.ts(x)` files. I am taking `npm run test:app` as an example

1. change file extensions to `.ts`.

   ```
   tests/__mocks__/variablesMock.ts
   tests/App_spec/App_functions.spec.tsx
   tests/App_spec/App_helpers.spec.tsx
   ```
2. add the following block to `src/typings/common.d.ts` or whichever the general type file is. this is to type the extra global attributes you add in `tests/__mocks__/variablesMock.ts`

   ```
   declare global {
     namespace NodeJS {
       interface Global {
      [name: string]: any;
     }
    }
   }
   ```
3. define the global attributes in your tests.

   A. `tests/App_spec/App_helpers.spec.tsx`

   ```
   const GLOBAL_OBJECT = (global as unknown) as {
     [name: string]: any;
   };
   const init_groups = GLOBAL_OBJECT.init_groups;
   const chromeLocalGetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeLocalGetSpy;
   const chromeLocalSetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeLocalSetSpy;
   const chromeSyncGetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeSyncGetSpy;
   const chromeSyncSetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeSyncSetSpy;
   const mockSet = GLOBAL_OBJECT.mockSet;
   const user = GLOBAL_OBJECT.user;
   ```

   B. `tests/App_spec/App_functions.spec.tsx`

   ```
   const GLOBAL_OBJECT = (global as unknown) as {
     [name: string]: any;
   };
   const init_groups = GLOBAL_OBJECT.init_groups;
   const chromeLocalGetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeLocalGetSpy;
   const chromeLocalSetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeLocalSetSpy;
   const chromeSyncGetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeSyncGetSpy;
   const chromeSyncSetSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeSyncSetSpy;
   const mockSet = GLOBAL_OBJECT.mockSet;
   const user = GLOBAL_OBJECT.user;
   const CONSTANTS = GLOBAL_OBJECT.CONSTANTS;
   const TUTORIAL_GROUP = GLOBAL_OBJECT.TUTORIAL_GROUP;
   const chromeBrowserActionSetBadgeTextSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeBrowserActionSetBadgeTextSpy;
   const chromeBrowserActionSetBadgeBackgroundColorSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeBrowserActionSetBadgeBackgroundColorSpy;
   const chromeBrowserActionSetTitleSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeBrowserActionSetTitleSpy;
   const chromeLocalRemoveSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeLocalRemoveSpy;
   const toggleDarkModeSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.toggleDarkModeSpy;
   const toggleSyncTimestampSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.toggleSyncTimestampSpy;
   const chromeSyncRemoveSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeSyncRemoveSpy;
   const exportedJSON = GLOBAL_OBJECT.exportedJSON;
   const chromeTabsRemoveSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeTabsRemoveSpy;
   const chromeTabsQuerySpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeTabsQuerySpy;
   const chromeTabsCreateSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeTabsCreateSpy;
   const chromeTabsMoveSpy = GLOBAL_OBJECT.chromeTabsMoveSpy;
   ```

I'm able to run the tests successfully with these steps `npm run test:app`.

```
 PASS  tests/App_spec/App_helpers.spec.tsx (6.081 s)
 PASS  tests/App_spec/App_functions.spec.tsx (11.93 s)
```

I also have a branch for you to look at if you want it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to be a step in the right direction, although a lot of correction is required to actually run successfully.

One thing I noticed is that the number of tests doubled (from 260ish to 626) and each test is much slower than before. The speed is likely due to typescript having to first compile the files, but why the extra tests?

Comment: I figured out that the `GLOBAL_OBJECT` should be defined in each test file or else the tests get re-run in that file if you export and import it there. I will have to figure out how to mock with typescript, but for now I think you answer is sufficient - Thank you so much!

Comment: Correct, `GLOBAL_OBJECT` should be defined in each file you plan to use `global` in. `GLOBAL_OBJECT` is just typing the `global` object so that typescript is able to compile the file. Also for the test re-runs - when you import anything (types or functions) from a .ts file, the whole file runs. So if you do `import {something} from './test-file.ts'`, the  `test-file.ts` runs as a script.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the behavior that I saw.

Regarding the `GLOBAL_OBJECT`, I simply added all the type definitions in the `declare global` block. This way I simply imported the necessary variables/functions from `global` in each file (skipping the `GLOBAL_OBJECT` entirely).

The next thing I need to understand is how to convert `js` files in `public/` to `ts` files. Currently I can do this locally, but `npm run build` causes an MIME type error on upload to the browser. I think the only option is to use webpack to build the compiled files, but need to double check.

Comment: Update: didn't need to use webpack after all to get the typescript in `public/` to work in the build. Simply needed to use `tsc -b FOLDERS_TO_CLEAN --clean` to clean the folders after the `tsc` command. So I did the following -> `tsc && npm run build && tsc -b some_folders_to_clean --clean` This allowed the MIME type to remain `.js` during the build process and everything worked well.